# Angular 2: Dynamically add component after n-th child

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there an elegant way I can implement the following solution in angular 2?

```
<div id="parent">
    <div>Child 1</div>
    <div>Child 2</div>
    <div>Child 3</div>
</div>

$("#parent > div:nth-child(2)").after("<div>foobar</div>");
```

I started liked this, but it is adding foobar after Child 1. I want it after Child 2.

[Dynamically insertion Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/BNEbjHso4GLoSkI4vRuL?p=preview)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using **`ViewChild`**, you can use **`ViewChildren`** to append the **`child component`** to **`last div`**. **`ViewChildren`** will view **`target div's`** children using **`QueryList`**

```
@ViewChildren('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target: QueryList(ViewContainerRef);
```

And need to grab last div like this,

```
this.cmpRef = this.target._results[2].createComponent(factory)  
//<---added ._results[2] which returns last div element.
//<---you can use ._result[0],_resultt[1],_result[2] to append dynamic component accordingly.
```

**Working Demo** : ***https://plnkr.co/edit/1KOK8gYgJnzAMUGnyy1P?p=preview***

**Note**: *Now, you can make it more dynamic if you want.*

---

**UPDATE**

As `_results` is a private member of `QueryList` use the following to prevent tslint errors.

```js
this.cmpRef = this.target.toArray()[index].createComponent(factory);
```

Comment: Do you know how could this be done to add an element BEFORE instead of after?? @micronyks

Comment: @micronyks `_results` is a private member of `QueryList`. Any suggestions? I think you've a typo using the brackets for QueryList. It should be QueryList<ViewContainerRef>, shouldn't it?

Comment: @ngfelixl this was answered long back in 2017. This might have changed. need to check the updates.

Comment: Figured it out for myself just now. One can use `this.target.toArray()[index]`.

Comment: @ngfelixl. you can update my answer with UPDATE title. so it might help to other readers too.